# Selecting Elements By InnerHTML with querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

Is there a way to select an element by innerHTML without using loops?
Can it be done using something like

```
document.querySelector('div[innerHTML="Sometext"]')
```

or

```
document.querySelector('div[textcontent="Sometext"]')
```

Comment: No it cannot. `querySelector` uses CSS selectors.

Comment: If you happen to use jQuery, it has a non-standard `:contains()` selector https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used jq "contains" to achieve this. for example if i want to get anchor tag with some inner Html then i would do something like this

```
 $('a:contains("sometext")')
```

Comment: How can you do this with vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    
    for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
    console.log(anchors[i].innerHTML)
    if(anchors[i].innerHTML == 'Products'){
    var menuButton = anchors[i].parentElement
    console.log(menuButton)
    break;
    
    }

}
```