# Get dropdown option element by display text

Tags: javascript, jquery, webdriver-io

I've currently been selecting dropdown elements by using:

```
$('#dropdownId option[value="value"]')
```

because most of my elements have been written as

```
<option value="value">value</option>
```

However, now I've come across some elements in this project that do not have the value attribute and instead look like

```
<option>value</option>
```

Now I'm struggling to select it using the same syntax that I used prior. I'd like to get the element (not just change the selection) using the same style as before, because it's a format that's used dynamically throughout the project. I've tried these so far:

```
$('#dropdownId option[value="value"]'); // doesn't work, I'd assume because it doesn't have a value attribute
$('#dropdownId option[text="value"]'); // Doesn't work, I'd assume because "text" isn't actually an attribute
$('#dropdownId option[label="value"]'); // Doesn't work, I'd assume because even though the value is used as the display text, it's not actually specified in the attributes.
```

I can't add a value="value" to the object, I don't have control over the html.

Edit: I realize that WebdriverIO, while it uses selectors similar to jQuery, doesn't necessarily have all of the same functionality. Nathan Hinchey's seems to work for normal jQuery though.

Comment: Does this this work? Answer to "Selecting Elements By InnerHTML with querySelector"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645734/5369466

Comment: You can use $('#dropdownId option').text()

Comment: @MirkoAcimovic that returns the text of the option. This question is asking for how to select the option.

Comment: Alternatively, you could select all the `option` tags that don't have a `value` (`$('option:not([value])')`), then just loop through the selection and `delete` the ones that don't have the `text`/`innerHtml` you want. That seems ugly, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen whole cloth from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645734/5369466):

You can use the jQuery `contains` selector

```
$('option:contains("value")')
```

Comment: This definitely works for jQuery. Unfortunately, I'm realizing that WebdriverIO, which my project uses and mostly copies jQuery selectors, doesn't work with this.

Comment: Are you able to use JavaScript to dynamically modify the HTML like in @ScottMarcus' answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically alter the HTML by adding a `value` attribute to `option` elements that don't have one and use the `.text()` of the `option` as the `.value`. Then, you could continue to select options as you already are. There are performance cost to altering the DOM (perhaps extensively) so beware of that.

```js
// Get all the <option> elements that don't have a "value" attribute and iterate the group
$("option:not([value])").each(function(){
  // Create the "value" attribute for the option and give it the value of the 
  // current option element's text.
  $(this).attr("value", $(this).text());
});

console.log($("select").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nathan Hinchey's answer works for people using base jQuery.

For people who are using WebDriverIO, I found [this discussion](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/570) which uses the selector

```
$('<element>*=<text>').
```

So, for my example, I used

```
$('option*=value')
```

However, I noticed that I couldn't nicely chain various selects in the single select, such as

```
$('select#selectId option*=value')  // WON'T work
```

If you need to chain any selections prior to it, such as maybe the select object containing the options, instead use

```
$('option*=value').$(elementSelector)
```

I'm currently using this to get the parent object, the  object.

```
$('option*=value').$('..')
```